# Tensorflow gather specific elements in 4d tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a 4D-tensor **Params** of dimensions [B, Y, X, N], and want to select a specific slice `n ∈ N` from it, such that my resulting tensor is of size [B, Y, X, 1] (or [B, Y, X]).

The specific slice should be the one containing the highest numbers on average; I obtain the indices like so:
`indices = tf.argmax(tf.reduce_sum(Params, [1,2]), 1)` (shape [B])

I tried different solutions using `gather` or `gather_nd`, but couldn't get it to work. There are multiple posts very similar to this, yet I wasn't able to apply one of the solutions presented there.

I'm running Tensorflow 1.3 so the fancy new axis-parameter for `gather` is available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the example code below the input is with shape `[2,3,4,5]` and the resulting shape is `[2,3,4]`.

The primary ideas are:

- It's easy to get a row instead of a column using `gather_nd`, so I switched the last two dimensions with `tf.transpose`.
- We need to convert the indices we get from `tf.argmax` (`indices` below) to something really usable (see `final_idx` below) in `tf.gather_nd`. The conversion is done via stacking of three components:

  - `[0 0 0 1 1 1]`
  - `[0 1 2 0 1 2]`
  - `[3 3 3 0 0 0]`

So we could go from `[3, 0]` to

```
 [[[0 0 3]
   [0 1 3]
   [0 2 3]]
  [[1 0 0]
   [1 1 0]
   [1 2 0]]].
```

```
Batch,Y,X = 2, 3, 4
tf.reset_default_graph()

data = np.arange(Batch*Y*X*5)
np.random.shuffle(data)

Params = tf.constant(np.reshape(data, [Batch, Y, X, 5]), dtype=tf.int32)
indices = tf.argmax(tf.reduce_sum(Params, [1,2]), 1)
indices = tf.cast(tf.reshape(tf.tile(tf.reshape(indices, [-1,1]), 
                                     [1,Y]), [-1]), tf.int32)

idx = tf.reshape(tf.range(batch_size), [-1,1])
idx = tf.reshape(tf.tile(idx, [1, y]), [-1])

inc = tf.reshape(tf.tile(tf.range(Y), [Batch]), [-1])
final_idx = tf.reshape(tf.stack([idx, inc, indices], 1), [Batch, Y, -1])
transposed = tf.transpose(Params, [0, 1, 3, 2])
slice = tf.gather_nd(transposed, final_idx)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print sess.run(Params)
    print sess.run(idx)    
    print sess.run(inc)
    print sess.run(indices)
    print sess.run(final_idx)
    print sess.run(slice)
```

```
[[[[ 22  38  68  49 119]
   [ 47  74 111 117  90]
   [ 14  32  31  12  75]
   [ 93  34  57   3  56]]

  [[ 69  21   4  94  39]
   [ 83  96  62 102  80]
   [ 55 113  48  98  29]
   [107  81  67  76  28]]

  [[ 53  51  77  66  63]
   [ 92 115 118 116  13]
   [ 43  78  15   1   0]
   [ 99  50  27  60  73]]]


 [[[ 97  88  91  64  86]
   [ 72 110  26  87  33]
   [ 70  30  41 114   5]
   [ 95  82  46  16  61]]

  [[109  71  45   8  40]
   [101   9  23  59  10]
   [ 37  65  44  11  19]
   [ 42 104 106 105  18]]

  [[112  58   7  17  89]
   [ 25  79 103  85  20]
   [ 35   6 108 100  36]
   [ 24  52   2  54  84]]]]

[0 0 0 1 1 1]
[0 1 2 0 1 2]
[3 3 3 0 0 0]

[[[0 0 3]
  [0 1 3]
  [0 2 3]]

 [[1 0 0]
  [1 1 0]
  [1 2 0]]]

[[[ 49 117  12   3]
  [ 94 102  98  76]
  [ 66 116   1  60]]

 [[ 97  72  70  95]
  [109 101  37  42]
  [112  25  35  24]]]
```

Comment: Probably I should clarify: The values of the indices-Tensor specify which slice to use. The result has to be obtained while the session is still running, as further calculations depend on it. I edited my original post, hope it's clearer now.

Comment: updated. Not sure if this is what you want. i will add some explanation later.

Comment: Wonderful. Now I also get why other examples didn't work. Hm, transposing is known to be a slow operation, I guess one could get around it by also generating indices for the third dimension, and concatenating those as well? Might be equally expensive.

On the other hand - can we get rid of one of the tiling operations if we transpose it to [Batch, N, Y, X] immediately? Then only enumerate Batch, and stack it onto index?